# How to select, copy and paste some columns from different files and create one file from them?

Tags: text-processing, awk, text, copy-paste, safecopy

I want to create and organize data in a file from a number of files by selecting parts of the columns of the given files. I have more than 10 file to copy the second, third and forth columns of each file and pasting them into a single file.

Comment: please define "column" in your context. It helps if you provide samples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 16):

This can also be done quite easily with `awk`.

```
$ awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' *.txt > collapsed_output.txt
```

#### Example

Here's some sample data.

```
$ seq 20 | paste - - - - - > sample.txt
```

Here's what the lines look like:

```
$ head sample.txt 
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
```

Now let's make 10 copies:

```
$ seq 10 | xargs -I{} cp sample.txt sample{}.txt
```

We now have the following files:

```
$ tree
.
|-- sample10.txt
|-- sample1.txt
|-- sample2.txt
|-- sample3.txt
|-- sample4.txt
|-- sample5.txt
|-- sample6.txt
|-- sample7.txt
|-- sample8.txt
|-- sample9.txt
`-- sample.txt
```

Now if we run our `awk` command:

```
$ awk '{print $2, $3, $4}' sample{1..10}.txt | column -t
2   3   4
7   8   9
12  13  14
17  18  19
2   3   4
7   8   9
12  13  14
17  18  19
2   3   4
7   8   9
12  13  14
17  18  19
...
```

Here I'm showing you the output for the first 3 files (`sample01.txt` ... `sample03.txt`). Also I'm formatting the output with the `column -t` command, but this is only for display purposes to make the output easier to see here on U&L.

Additional formatting could just as easily been done within the `awk` command but that seemed to be beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [command line utility named `cut`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/). It can extract columns if they are separated by a unique delimiter. To recombine the parts you can use [`paste`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/).

If you have, for example a typical comma-separated format

```
$ cat debts.csv
Name,Age,Debt
Alice,20,1337
Bob,30,42

$ cat pets.csv
Name,Pet
Alice,Dog
Bob,Cat
```

you could extract names and debts with

```
$ cut -d, -f1,3 debts.csv
Name,Debt
Alice,1337
Bob,42
```

and combine debts with pets using

```
$ cut -d, -f2 pets.csv | paste -d, debts.csv -
Name,Age,Debt,Pet
Alice,20,1337,Dog
Bob,30,42,Cat
```

- With `cut` and `paste`,  `-d` determines the delimiter for the fields,
- `-f` selects the columns to extract for `cut` and
- `-` directs to use the standard input (i.e. in the latter `paste` case, from the pipe) instead of a file.